# jQuery : Change Menu Item CSS on click

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing an application using ASP.NET-MVC 4. Here, I am dynamically loading the menu in the layout page. I have created a partial view to load the menus dynamically and included that in the layout page as follows:

MenuModel.cs:

```
public class MenuModel
{
    public List<MainMenu> MainMenuModel { get; set; }        
}

public class MainMenu
{
    public int MainMenuID;
    public string MainMenuName;
    public string MainMenuController;
    public string MainMenuAction;
}
```

PartialController.cs:

```
using Insights.Models;

[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult LoadMenu()
{
    MenuModel ObjMenuModel = new MenuModel();
    ObjMenuModel.MainMenuModel = new List<MainMenu>();
    ObjMenuModel.MainMenuModel = GetMainMenu();
    return PartialView(ObjMenuModel);
}

public List<MainMenu> GetMainMenu()
{
    List<MainMenu> ObjMainMenu = new List<MainMenu>();
    var context = new InsightsEntities();
    ObjMainMenu = context.Insights_mMenu.Where(m => m.parentMenuUID == 0).Select(x => new MainMenu()
        {
            MainMenuID = x.menuUID,
            MainMenuName = x.menuName,
            MainMenuController = x.menuURLController,
            MainMenuAction = x.menuURLAction
        }).ToList();

        return ObjMainMenu;
}
```

LoadMenu.cshtml: (Partial View)

```
@model Insights.Models.MenuModel

<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/MADMIN_files/style(2).css" />
<ul class="sidebar-menu on-click" id="main-menu">
<li class="active">
    <div class="sidebar-menu-item-wrapper">
        <a href="#">
            <i class="icon-home"></i>
            <span>Home</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</li>
@{
    foreach (var MenuItem in Model.MainMenuModel)
    {

    <li class="active">
        <div class="sidebar-menu-item-wrapper">
            <a href='@Url.Action(@MenuItem.MainMenuAction, @MenuItem.MainMenuController)'><span>@MenuItem.MainMenuName</span></a>
        </div>
    </li>

     }
  }
</ul>
```

_Layout.cshtml:

```
<div id="sidebar">
     @{ Html.RenderAction("LoadMenu", "Partial"); }
</div>
```

This is my screen:
[image]

The screen shows the page which belongs to the Menu "Reports". Here, I want to highlight the clicked menu by changing its css as "active". There are two classes "active" and "inactive". How to achieve this when we load the menus dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

You can then use something like this to determine the 'Parent' action and controller name from within the Child action. This can be compared to the values for each menu item to see if it is indeed the active menu item, and if so you can set an IsActive property on the menu item. Then simply use the IsActive property to decide whether to add the css class when rendering the menu.

`string actionName = this.ControllerContext.ParentActionViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
 string controllerName = this.ControllerContext.ParentActionViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();`